# Como agregar elementos a una lista del modelo mediante JavaScript en asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, lista, modal

La duda que traigo es la siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente `ViewModel`:

```
public class TareasAltaViewModel
    {
        public string Modo { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Asunto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Observación")]
        public string Observacion { get;  set; }
        public string Responsable { get; set; }  
        public int ResponsableId { get; set; }
        public int Prioridad { get; set; }
        public List<Prioridad> ListaPrioridad { get; set; }
        public List<Equipo> ListaEquipos { get; set; }
        public int EquipoId { get; set; }
        public string Suscripto { get; set; }
        public string EmailSuscripto { get; set; }
        public int SuscriptoId { get; set; }
        public List<SuscriptoDetalle> ListaSuscriptos { get; set; }


    }

    public class SuscriptoDetalle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prioridad
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
    }
```

Lo que necesito lograr es que en la vista cuando agrego a un suscripto, primero el nombre del suscripto se autocomplete, una vez que selecciono al suscripto, apretar el boton agregar y que el mismo se agregue a la lista de suscriptos, así cuando llamo al modal con el botón detalles, me muestre el nombre y mail de los suscriptos y me de la opción de modificarlos. Básicamente el problema creo que lo tengo en el momento en que quiero añadir un nuevo suscripto a la lista!

La vista es la siguiente:

```
@

    using (Html.BeginForm("Alta", "Tareas", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
    <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2">Suscriptos</p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Suscripto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SuscriptoId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.EmailSuscripto)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ListaSuscriptos)
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="guardarSuscripto"> Agregar </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Editar </button>
        </div>


        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(Inicio)
            var i = 1;

            function Inicio() {
     $("#Suscripto").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ResponsablesObtener", "Tareas")',
                            datatype: "json",
                            data: {
                                filtro: request.term
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: val.Nombre,
                                        value: val.Nombre,
                                        usuarioId: val.Id,
                                        UsuarioEmail: val.Mail
                                    }
                                }))
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#SuscriptoId").val(ui.item.usuarioId);
                        $("#SuscriptoEmail").val(ui.item.UsuarioEmail);
                    },
                    messages: {
                        noResults: '',
                        results: function() {}
                    }
                });

     $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal'), function () {
                    $('#myInput').focus()


      }
```

Básicamente pase algunos fragmentos del código, el código es un poco mas largo, pero para no pasar cosas sin sentidos y ensuciar la consulta tome algunas partes nomas!

La función que a mi parecer estaría faltando sería esta:

```
 $("[id$=guardarSuscripto").click(function () {}
```

Y ahí agregar el suscripto seleccionado a la lista de suscriptos cada vez que clickeo, la verdad no se como hacerlo.